# Zend Framework 2 - Doctrine 2 - How to use command line under Windows

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, command-line-interface, zend-framework2

I found this [website](http://wildlyinaccurate.com/useful-doctrine-2-console-commands) listing several interesting `Doctrine` CLI commands.

I set up a Doctrine model class like it is [described](http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/01/using-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-2/) in one of these tutorials.

But I still wonder how to use the CLI commands. How can Zend or Doctrine know where my classes are and how does Windows know that my Doctrine executable lies within my projects library?

Does anyone know how to utilize these CLI commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine cli is based on the symfony console package.

If you use composer for installing, take a look in the `vendor/bin` directory. You will find `.bat` files for the doctrine cli there.

Comment: alright, I found this one. Still I wonder how this batch file knows about my entities deep inside my Zend project...

Comment: It basically runs the whole zf2 mvc, so it knows where all your classes are from your zf2 config files. Take a look here https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/bin/doctrine-module.php#L46